# Music Player Daemon not working, no songs playing

Tags: linux, audio, mp3, music, mpd

So I just installed MPD together with MPC and NCMPCPP but I can't get it to work. There is 1 song in the database, according to NCMPCPP (Show server info) but there are no Artists or Albums. I downloaded a song from YouTube using `youtube-dl-mp3`, but it doesn't show up. When I run `mpc play` it says `volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off` (I don't know if this is right or not), and when I run `mpc current` after that I get no output. No song is playing. Here is my `mpd.conf` file:

```
db_file "~/.config/mpd/database"
log_file "~/.config/mpd/mpd.log"
music_directory "~/Music"
auto_update "yes"
bind_to_address "127.0.0.1"
audio_output {
    type "alsa"
    name "HD-Audio Generic"
    device "plug:dmix"
}
```

I'm not 100% sure "HD-Audio Generic" is correct, I got it from `alsamixer` (where it says `Card: <sound_card>` at the top).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I found the solution: `mpc add "$(mpc ls)"`. I completely forgot to run this command - my bad.